# Create a service proof box to test mobile without network available

Tags: wireless

Hello for a project i need to test the behavior an application for mobile phone in situation there is no cellular data available. in some cases i have successfully been able to test this in the lift at my work place, however at home i cant do the test as there is no lift :). i tried to recreate this situation by wrapping a box with aluminum foils without success.

Any suggestion how i can create a box in which there will be no cellular network inside ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [Faraday Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Connect your aluminum foil box to an electrical ground, and that will prevent cellular signals from passing in/out of the box.

Comment: It doesn't have to grounded. It *does* have to be continuous; any hole larger than the mesh in your microwave door will let a signal in.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i decided to look for an old phone and will just remove the antenna

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling Airplane mode? Most modern phones support airplane mode which disabled cellular data and wi-if.

Comment: good idea, however in airplane mode the phone does not send events to sim.